# Jira gadgets development

Tags: java, jquery, jira, jira-plugin

I need to develop some jira gadget.
The gadget must have a chart and the possibility to insert external data and diplay it in the chart.

I have been trying the tutorial on atlassian documentation but I don't see any instruction on how to insert charts and how to do it, I think are made with JQuery (if it's correct, there are sample to use? I'm not really in to JQuery). Another problem that I found, is that there is no much explenation on how to get data from Jira (directly). I have seen the "jira api" (all the java interfaces) but I couldn't really get them work.

Anybody that know some better tutorial, gadget source example or that can help me on getting started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, developing JIRA gadgets with charts is harder than it should be. I have spent some time recently creating a plugin for a client that uses the JIRA system gadgets with some changes and it has been too much work. The charts in JIRA gadgets are created using JFreeChart.

If you can use an external visualization library such as Google Visualization then this example may help: https://labs.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JUA/JIRA+User+Activity
Change the pom.xml to refer to JIRA 4.2 at the bottom in two places and it compiles fine using the usual Atlassian PDK.

~Matt